# Cannot call 'operator <' with argument 'expr0'='bar_1s_prev_close'. An argument of 'float[]' type was used but a 'simple float' is expected

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Cannot call 'operator <' with argument 'expr0'='bar_1s_prev_close'. An argument of 'float[]' type was used but a 'simple float' is expected.

I don't quite understand why it doesn't work can someone please help thx!

```
min_bars_5m = input.timeframe(title="5 min bar imbalence", defval="5m")
bar_5m_prev_low = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,  timeframe=min_bars_5m, expression=low[1])
bar_5m_prev_high = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,  timeframe=min_bars_5m, expression=high[1])


min_bars_1s = input.timeframe(title="1s bar close", defval="10s")
bar_1s_prev_close = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid,  timeframe=min_bars_1s, expression=close)

float bear_imbalence=0

if bar_1s_prev_close < bar_5m_prev_low
    bear_imbalence := low / 1.02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use request.security_lower_tf and this send back an **array of float,** not an float. So you are trying to compare an array to a float, which throw the error.

This array contains all the values for the lower time frame your requested.

So you must choose which value you want to compare.
For example, if you want to compare the first value, you should use :

```
bar_1s_prev_close_First_Value = array.get(bar_1s_prev_close,0)

if bar_1s_prev_close_First_Value < bar_5m_prev_low
    bear_imbalance := low / 1.02
```

See : [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request{dot}security_lower_tf](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request%7Bdot%7Dsecurity_lower_tf)

Comment: thank you so much for dedicating your time to helping others!